# Java regex lookbehind is not working as js regex lookbehind

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

I had this objective :

Given string : `"Part1-part2-part3-part4-part5"` 
Split it on second occurrence of '-', 
So I expect an array `[ "Part1-part2", "part3-part4-part5" ]`

What I did :

```
"Part1-part2-part3-part4-part5".split("(?<=^\\w+-\\w+)-"
```

But result on jdk 8 : 
It does not find match of 2nd '-', **and returns the entire string**. 
Evidence : https://ideone.com/myWppm

But when I tried on online regex processing websites and node.js (or chrome) [Believe me modern js supports lookbehind] the **result is as expected**. 
Evidence : https://ideone.com/ttQWNr

Hack that I'm using right now (does not qualify to be a solution) :

Using lookahead instead of lookbehind, *3rd occurrence of '-' from the end* 
`"Part1-part2-part3-part4-part5".split("-(?=\\w+-\\w+-\\w+$)");`

Answer (score 2):

Java does support finite lookbehind using a quantifier for example `{0,100}`

To match any char except a hyphen, you could use `[^-]` which is a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated).

If you want to exclude matching newlines, you could extend it to `[^-\\r\\n]`

You might use:

```
(?<=^[^-]{0,100}-[^-]{0,100})-
```

In parts

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, assert what is on the left is

  - `^` Start of string
  - `[^-]{0,100}`- Match 0 - 100 times any char except `-`, then match the first `-`
  - `[^-]{0,100} Match 0 - 100 times any char except`-`
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `-` Match the second `-` to split on

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/i9fBSH/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/js8ahy)

For example

```
System.out.println(
    Arrays.toString(
        "Part1-part2-part3-part4-part5".split("(?<=^[^-]{0,100}-[^-]{0,100})-")
    )
);
```

Output

```
[Part1-part2, part3-part4-part5]
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `split()`, use matching:

```
String input = "Part1-part2-part3-part4-part5";
String regex = "(\\w+-\\w+)-(.*)"
String[] result; // just to simulate result of split()
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);
if (m.matches()) {
    result = new String[] { m.group(1), m.group(2) };
} else {
    result = new String[] { input };
}
```

Sure it's a bit more code, but you can easily enhance the regex to perform more validation, e.g. no special characters other than `-` (and `_` apparently), even for the text after the second dash.

Comment: Hey, I've to pass this regex to some code which underlying using spark-sql's split function. I do not have option to pass some lambda / custom function object since it will be like a blackbox to apache spark, and it wont be able to optimise the operation.  
So as solution I need only a single regex.
To get some idea, check here : https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-split-dataframe-column-into-multiple-columns/

Answer (score 1):

Variable width lookbehinds are not supported by Java.  Assuming your input string would *always* have five hyphen separated terms, we could instead phrase the splitting logic by checking that there be two hyphens in front before spltting:

```
String input = "Part1-part2-part3-part4-part5";
String[] parts = input.split("-(?=[^-]+-[^-]+-[^-]+$)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

This prints:

```
[Part1-part2, part3-part4-part5]
```

Comment: Hey, I've to pass this regex to some code which underlying using spark-sql's split function. I do not have option to pass some lambda / custom function object since it will be like a blackbox to apache spark, and it wont be able to optimise the operation.  
So as solution I need only a single regex.
To get some idea, check here : https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-split-dataframe-column-into-multiple-columns/

Comment: I have given you a single regex.  I don't understand your comment.